# Knockout.js: make id based on text binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to have something like following code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: subTopics -->
    <div id='subtopic-name-here'>
<!-- /ko -->
```

That is I want to have id of my div as the name of subtopic(`data-bind="text:name"`).How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `attr` binding for this:

```
<!-- ko foreach: subTopics -->
    <div data-bind="attr: {'id': name}"></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html